# Problema frame pagina web

Tags: html, iframe

Soy todavia bastente novato en esto, pero quiero colocar una pagina web dentro de otra con un frame. El problema es que me rechaza la conexión la pagina web del frame. Hay alguna forma de que me la acepte?? ¿Qué tendría que hacer? El error que me da es que me dice que no se puede conectar -> [www.stripe.com](http://www.stripe.com) refused to conect

Comment: Especifica tanto en el título de la pregunta como en la pregunta en sí _cuál_ es el error que aparece. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Puede estar pasandote eso por que no tienes permiso de incluir el sitio de ellos en el tuyo, para ello debes contactarte con el administrador del sitio

Comment: Eso es lo que he pensado pero habría alguna forma de llegar a hacer algo parecido. Es decir colocar la pagina web de stripe en mi página

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ver las cabeceras de la respuesta usando cUrl desde una shell de linux:

```
curl -v https://stripe.com/es
```

que devuelve muchas, pero la relativas a la seguridad que te concierne es básicamente una:

```
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
```

La cual, segun la explicación encontrada en este [enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options), dice lo siguiente:

> El encabezado de respuesta HTTP X-Frame-Options puede ser usado para
> indicar si debería permitírsele a un navegador renderizar una página
> en un `<frame>`, `<iframe>` o `<object>` . Las páginas webs pueden usarlo
> para evitar ataques de clickjacking , asegurándose que su contenido no
> es embebido en otros sitios.

Eso es lo que está impidiéndote usar un `<iframe>` apuntando a esa web.

Y ante la pregunta de como colocar la página web de stripe en tu página, pues no se que decirte, no entiendo el propósito.

Quizás podria ayudarte mejor si supiera que quieres conseguir realmente. Si por ejemplo es para mostrar exactamente lo de ellos no hace falta que la pongas como un `<iframe>`, sino que redireccionas la petición de tu web hacia su web (tampoco es que tenga mucho sentido, claro). O bien pones un simple enlace para que tus visitas puedan visitar la otra comodamente (pero saliendo de tu web).

Comment: Muchas gracias de antemano. El problema es que mi jefe no quiere que el cliente cuando use la web de stripe salga de la nuestra, por eso tengo el problema. Sino lo mandaría por un enlace y ya está, pero mi jefe quiere que el cliente acceda a stripe y no abandone nuestra web. ¿Se te ocurre alguna forma?

Comment: Pon un enlace con el atributo `target="_blank"` para que vuestra pestaña siga activa y fuerce al visitante a abrir una pestaña nueva con la web de stripe.  Piensa que si no lo puedes hacer con un frame, aunque te dedicaras a scrappear la página de stripe.com y mostrarla en un `<div>` en vuestra página, como si se tratara de una frame, sus enlaces seguirian apuntando a `stripe.com/es` (si no son relativos, en cuyo caso aun peor porque les daria un error 404 al clicarlos). Y tampoco es plan de scrapear la pagina y modificar todos sus enlaces vinculandolos a enlaces vuestros para que funcionen.